# Create content items for others in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, .net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

In Orchard CMS, there is an option to "Show editor for owner" in Common Part options.
But, as far as I see, turning this option affects only site owner's ("admin" user) ability to create content items for others.

How to make other roles do that?

Comment: You can't: this would enable elevation of privilege. But it doesn't affect the ability to create content, only the ability to blame others for what you create. What's the scenario?

Comment: In perfect world I would agree. But in my case, the client wants to be able to create content items for their clients. Just when they call and ask for that. And that would happen when their clients are offline and have to add the entry anyways.